# Renaming files listed within a listbox

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I'm trying to create a little program thats able to alter the names of shotcuts, from a listbox-index.
I've created a button wich list every file with the targeted "extension"(targeted with combobox1), from where I want another button to be able to alter the files names:

**Button 1 code(Searching for the files):**

```
Dim kilde As New FolderBrowserDialog
If kilde.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim mappe = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(kilde.SelectedPath)
    txtbSti.Text = kilde.SelectedPath
End If

For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(txtbSti.Text, "*" & ComboBox1.Text & "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    If File.Exists(f) Then
        With ListBox1
            With .Items
                .Add(f)
            End With
        End With
    End If
Next f
```

This gives me a list with the desired files.
Is there a way, to rename the files, in my case,listed within listbox1, line by line?

**Button 2 (not functioning)**

```
    For Each r As String In ListBox1.Items
        System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(ComboBox1.Text, " ")
    Next r
```

Comment: In this case, remove the automatic generated extension ".avi - Shortcut"

Comment: @Freshman: is that an extension or just part of the file-name? Can you show some sample file-names and the desired result?

Comment: oh, sorry, it's a part of the name; the file is named, example; J:\Homemovies\Jumping around.avi - Shortcut.lnk, I want to remove the ".avi - Shortcut" part of the name on the actual file(s) listed within the listbox1 that is set up to find all the files within a 
targeted folder with that particular extension within it's name; J:\Homemovies\Jumping around.lnk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `File.Move` to "rename" a file:

`System.IO.File.Move("oldfilename", "newfilename")`

For example:

```
For Each oldFilePath As String In ListBox1.Items
    If System.IO.File.Exists(oldFilePath) Then
        Dim dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(oldFilePath)
        Dim newFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine( dir, "newFileName")
        System.IO.File.Move(oldFilePath, newFilePath)
    End If
Next
```

**Edit**: *In this case, remove the automatic generated extension ".avi - Shortcut"*

If you just want to change an extension you can use `Path.ChangeExtension`:

```
System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(oldFilePath, "new_extension")
```

**Update**: *oh, sorry, it's a part of the name; the file is named, example; J:\Homemovies\Jumping around.avi - Shortcut.lnk, I want to remove the ".avi - Shortcut" part of the name on the actual file(s) listed within the listbox1 that is set up to find all the files within a targeted folder with that particular extension within it's name; J:\Homemovies\Jumping around.lnk*

You can use `String.Replace`:

```
Dim name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(oldFilePath).ToLowerInvariant()
Dim newName = name.Replace(".avi - shortcut.", ".")
Dim newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(oldFilePath), newName)
```

**Update2**: *still can't get either of those solutions to work*

Here is a complete working sample:

First, read the shortcuts from your directory:

```
Dim dir = "C:\Temp\Homemovies"
For Each fn In Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(dir, "*avi - shortcut*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(fn)
Next
```

Second (in your button-click handler), rename those .Ink files by removing the part that contains(substring)`"avi - shortcut"`, also handling the case that it already exists:

```
For Each fn As String In ListBox1.Items
    If File.Exists(fn) Then
        Dim folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(fn)
        Dim fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn)
        Dim extension = Path.GetExtension(fn)
        Dim dotParts = fileName.Split("."c)
        Dim allButAviShortCut = From part In dotParts
                                Where part.IndexOf("avi - shortcut", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = -1
        Dim newFileName = String.Join(".", allButAviShortCut)
        Dim newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, newFileName & extension)
        Dim number = 0
        While File.Exists(newPath)
            ' exists already, append number
            number += 1
            Dim newFileNameWithNum = String.Format("{0}_{1}", newFileName, number)
            newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, newFileNameWithNum & extension)
        End While
        System.IO.File.Move(fn, newPath)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Oh, sorry I'm not that good at explaining :) To sum it up. Once the folder is selected (button 1) and all the files with ".avi - Shortcut.lnk (set by combobox1)" are listed in listbox1. I want the other function (button 2) to take the path to the files, one by one, and rename them to the same name minus the text in combobox1. Sorry for the late respond, fell asleep yesterday, my apologies :)

Comment: @Freshman: _"i can't help without more informations"_ meant that i don't know what went wrong, you haven't even mentioned an error.

Comment: Oh, sorry again, I'm not much of a readed either it seems :) I'm testing your first example, and this is the error it gives me: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" & "Can't create a file that already exist"

Comment: @Freshman: i've edited my answer again to provide full working sample code(_Update2_).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

- `ListBox1` contains list of all files in the selected directory.
- `txtbSti` is the text box which holds the `path` to the selected directory.
- Each file is renamed as `New_fileX` where `X` is the index of the file in the `ListBox1`

**Now take a look into the code:**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim i As Integer = 0
  For Each r As String In ListBox1.Items
    i += 1
    My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(txtbSti.Text & ":\" & r, "New_file" & i & ".txt")
  Next r
End Sub
```